# Delete specific string from files in directories

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have tried so many variations of deleting a regex string from the /var/www/ folder and cannot get it to work. Maybe this is a dumb syntax issue?

```
regex = /@require\(dirname\(__FILE__\).'\/dir\/file.php'\);/g
```

Tried:

```
sed -i '//@require\(dirname\(__FILE__\).'\/dir\/file.php'\);/g/d' /var/www/*


awk '{gsub("/@require\(dirname\(__FILE__\).'\/dir\/file.php'\);/g", "");}' /var/www/*
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should escape an output of @require(dirname(**FILE**) as well. Or - the easier way - you can also use a different separator in sed. Anyway, I would suggest escaping that character. -i option is fine.

```
[kan@pckan ~]$ echo "line starts in here /var/www/dir/file.txt oh yes" | sed 's|/var/www/dir/file.txt||g'
line starts in here  oh yes
```

To sum up:

1. Escape sed's separator in search string
2. Start with 's...' in sed